# dotnet publish results in "There is no application host available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier" using RID "osx.11.0-arm64"

Tags: .net, apple-silicon

I'm using Apple silicon M1 processor, macOS Big Sur with dotnet 6 preview 7 SDK (released August 10th).

dotnet publish command with RID being "osx.11.0-arm64" results in the error "There is no application host available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier".

This RID is listed in the [runtime.json](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms/src/runtime.json) file in the dotnet GitHub repo. I have tried also using the RIDs walking back in the RID tree in the runtime.json file all the way to osx-arm64 and all have the same error.

Is there actually an application host available for this RID in dotnet 6 preview 7? Any ideas on what I may be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Not all of the runtime identifiers are included in the SDK. See https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31180 which links to this file in source https://github.com/dotnet/installer/blob/8b9782a074c51ef9f8b8b0608870c23ed77df7f5/src/redist/targets/GenerateBundledVersions.targets#L181-L192 which specifies which runtime identifiers are included in the SDK.